# ssl handshake error websphere application server

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, websphere-8

```
[11/4/15 15:25:33:655 IST] 000000a0 SystemOut     O Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: bluepages.ibm.com]
[11/4/15 15:25:33:655 IST] 000000a0 SystemOut     O ***
[11/4/15 15:25:33:655 IST] 000000a0 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 90
[11/4/15 15:25:33:855 IST] 000000a0 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[11/4/15 15:25:33:855 IST] 000000a0 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
[11/4/15 15:25:33:865 IST] 000000a0 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, called closeSocket()
[11/4/15 15:25:33:865 IST] 000000a0 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I have SSL_TLSv2 in websphere application server. Still getting this error, How to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error - you will need to check on few parameters below.

1. Have you trusted the remote certificate ?
   ( accept or added it to trust store)
2. Does any of the  cipher suites match?

You can try to access the service URL in the browser and check for the certificate and cipher suite.